# Delay in Displaying Popup in Android App jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, popup, android-jetpack-compose, android-softkeyboard

I'm currently working on an keyboard app where I have implemented a popup that should display instantly when a key press. I am using jetpack compose own PopUp. However, I'm experiencing an unexpected delay in the popup's appearance. I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this delay issue.
When key is pressed it should instantly shows up and i have implemented a handler that hides it after 250 mili second. But i shows after delay of about some hundred mili-second. The popup should appear instantly when the trigger action is performed, without any noticeable delay.

This is my PopUp.kt.

```
package com.soloftech.keyboard.presentation.layout


import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.colorResource
import androidx.compose.ui.res.dimensionResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.compose.ui.window.Popup
import androidx.compose.ui.window.PopupProperties
import com.soloftech.keyboard.R

@Composable
fun PopupScreen(
    label: String,
    isVisible: Boolean
) {
    val popupWidth = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.key_width)
    val popupHeight = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.key_height)
    val cornerSize = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.key_borderRadius)

    if (isVisible) {
        Popup(
            properties = PopupProperties(
                clippingEnabled = true,
                dismissOnClickOutside = true
            ),
            alignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
        ) {
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .size(width = popupWidth, height = popupHeight * 2)
                    .background(
                        colorResource(id = R.color.PopUpColor),
                        RoundedCornerShape(cornerSize)
                    ),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = label,
                    color = colorResource(id = R.color.KeyTextColor),
                    fontSize = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.key_popup_textSize).value.sp
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun PopUpPreview() {
    PopupScreen(label = "F", isVisible = true)
}
```

Here i am calling this.

```
        if (key.shouldShowPopUp) {
            // Display a pop-up screen if Clicked
            PopupScreen(
                label = popUpLabel,
                isVisible = isPopupVisible.value
            )
        }
```

IsPopUpVisible value and handler code is here.

```
.pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTapGestures(
                onTap = {
                    // Handle tap gesture on the key
                    isPopupVisible.value = true
                    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                        isPopupVisible.value = false
                    }, 250)
                    if (context != null) {
                        playSound(context = context)
                    }
                    vibrate(vibrator)

                    when (key.labelMain) {
                        LABEL_ABC -> onLayoutSwitchClick()
                        LABEL_123 -> onSymbolsLayoutSwitchClick()
                        LABEL_EXTENDED_SYMBOLS -> onExtendedSymbolsSwitchClick()
                        LABEL_SYMBOLS -> onSymbolsLayoutSwitchClick()
                        LABEL_NUMBERS -> onNumbersSwitchClick()
                        LABEL_CAPS -> {
                            onCapsClick()
                        }

                        else -> onKeyPressed()
                    }
                },
```

And here is declaration of isPopupVisible.

```
val isPopupVisible = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
```

Here is whole CustomKey code.

```
package com.soloftech.keyboard.presentation.layout


import android.content.Context
import android.os.Vibrator
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectHorizontalDragGestures
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectTapGestures
import androidx.compose.foundation.indication
import androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource
import androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.PressInteraction
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.defaultMinSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material.ripple.rememberRipple
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.pointerInput
import androidx.compose.ui.res.colorResource
import androidx.compose.ui.res.dimensionResource
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.constraintlayout.compose.ConstraintLayout
import com.soloftech.keyboard.R
import com.soloftech.keyboard.domain.constants.LABEL_123
import com.soloftech.keyboard.domain.constants.LABEL_ABC
import com.soloftech.keyboard.domain.constants.LABEL_CAPS
import com.soloftech.keyboard.domain.constants.LABEL_EXTENDED_SYMBOLS
import com.soloftech.keyboard.domain.constants.LABEL_NUMBERS
import com.soloftech.keyboard.domain.constants.LABEL_SPACE
import com.soloftech.keyboard.domain.constants.LABEL_SYMBOLS
import com.soloftech.keyboard.domain.keyboard.Key
import com.soloftech.keyboard.domain.playSound
import com.soloftech.keyboard.domain.showPopUp
import com.soloftech.keyboard.domain.vibrate

@Composable
fun CustomKey(
    key: Key,
    isCapsEnabled: Boolean = false,
    isCapsLockEnabled: Boolean = false,
    onKeyPressed: () -> Unit,
    onDragGesture: (Float) -> Unit,
    onLongKeyPressed: () -> Unit,
    onLongKeyPressedEnd: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier,
    onLayoutSwitchClick: () -> Unit,
    onExtendedSymbolsSwitchClick: () -> Unit,
    onNumbersSwitchClick: () -> Unit,
    onSymbolsLayoutSwitchClick: () -> Unit,
    onCapsClick: () -> Unit,
    onCapsClickToLock: () -> Unit,
    context: Context?,
    vibrator: Vibrator? = null,
    iconResourceId: Int = key.icon,
    textColor: Color = colorResource(id = R.color.KeyTextColor),
    imeAction: Int? = null
) {
    // State to track the visibility of the pop-up
    val isPopupVisible = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    // Determine the background color of the key based on whether it's a special character
    val keyColor = if (key.isSpecialCharacter) {
        colorResource(id = R.color.SpecialKeyBackground)
    } else {
        colorResource(id = R.color.KeyBackground)
    }

    // Define the shape of the key based on its label
    val keyShape =
        if (key.shouldBeRounded) {
            RoundedCornerShape(56.dp)
        } else {
            RoundedCornerShape(6.dp)
        }

    // Calculate the main label of the key, considering Caps and Caps Lock state
    val labelMain = remember(key.labelMain, isCapsEnabled, isCapsLockEnabled) {
        if (isCapsEnabled || isCapsLockEnabled) {
            key.labelMain.uppercase()
        } else {
            key.labelMain
        }
    }

    // Determine the icon to display on the key
    val icon = when (key.labelMain) {
        LABEL_CAPS -> {
            if (isCapsEnabled) {
                R.drawable.caps_lock_on
            } else if (isCapsLockEnabled) {
                R.drawable.caps_lock_on_locked
            } else {
                R.drawable.caps_lock_off
            }
        }

        "Done" -> {
            when (imeAction) {
                EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE -> R.drawable.done_icon
                EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH -> R.drawable.search_icon
                EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT -> R.drawable.next_icon
                EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND -> R.drawable.send_icon
                EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO -> R.drawable.go_icon
                EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NONE -> R.drawable.keyboard_return
                EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_PREVIOUS -> R.drawable.previous_icon
                else -> key.icon
            }
        }

        else -> iconResourceId
    }

    // State to track long press
    var isLongPressed by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    // Determine the label for the pop-up
    val popUpLabel = if (isLongPressed) key.labelSecondary ?: "" else key.labelMain

    // Interaction source for detecting gestures
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

    ConstraintLayout(modifier = modifier
        .clip(keyShape)
        .background(color = keyColor)
        .indication(
            interactionSource = interactionSource, indication = rememberRipple(
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.white), radius = 256.dp
            )
        )
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTapGestures(
                onTap = {
                    // Handle tap gesture on the key
                    onClick(
                        isPopupVisible = isPopupVisible,
                        context = context,
                        vibrator = vibrator
                    )

                    when (key.labelMain) {
                        LABEL_ABC -> onLayoutSwitchClick()
                        LABEL_123 -> onSymbolsLayoutSwitchClick()
                        LABEL_EXTENDED_SYMBOLS -> onExtendedSymbolsSwitchClick()
                        LABEL_SYMBOLS -> onSymbolsLayoutSwitchClick()
                        LABEL_NUMBERS -> onNumbersSwitchClick()
                        LABEL_CAPS -> {
                            onCapsClick()
                        }

                        else -> onKeyPressed()
                    }
                },
                onDoubleTap = {
                    // Handle double tap gesture on the key
                    if (key.labelMain == LABEL_CAPS) {
                        onCapsClickToLock()
                    } else {
                        onKeyPressed()
                        onKeyPressed()
                    }
                    onClick(
                        isPopupVisible = isPopupVisible,
                        context = context,
                        vibrator = vibrator
                    )
                },
                onLongPress = {
                    // Handle long press gesture on the key
                    isLongPressed = true
                    if (key.labelMain == LABEL_CAPS) {
                        onCapsClickToLock()
                    } else {
                        onLongKeyPressed()
                    }
                    isPopupVisible.value = true
                    if (context != null) {
                        playSound(context = context)
                    }
                    vibrate(vibrator)
                },
                onPress = { offset ->
                    // Handle press gesture on the key
                    val press = PressInteraction.Press(offset)
                    interactionSource.emit(press)
                    tryAwaitRelease()
                    if (isPopupVisible.value) {
                        isPopupVisible.value = false
                    }
                    onLongKeyPressedEnd()
                    isLongPressed = false
                    interactionSource.emit(PressInteraction.Release(press))
                })

            detectHorizontalDragGestures { _, dragAmount ->
                // Handle horizontal drag gesture on the key
                onDragGesture(dragAmount)
            }
        }
        .defaultMinSize(minHeight = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.key_height).value.dp)
    ) {
        if (key.shouldShowIcon) {
            // Display an icon on the key
            Icon(painter = painterResource(id = icon),
                contentDescription = key.contentDescription,
                tint = textColor,
                modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(createRef()) {
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                })
        } else {
            when (key.labelMain) {
                LABEL_123, LABEL_ABC, LABEL_SPACE, LABEL_SYMBOLS ->
                    AutoResizedText(text = key.labelMain,
                        color = textColor,
                        modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(createRef()) {
                            top.linkTo(parent.top)
                            bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                            start.linkTo(parent.start)
                            end.linkTo(parent.end)
                        })

                else -> Text(
                    text = labelMain,
                    color = textColor,
                    fontSize = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.key_textSize).value.sp,
                    modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(createRef()) {
                        top.linkTo(parent.top)
                        bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                        start.linkTo(parent.start)
                        end.linkTo(parent.end)
                    })
            }
        }

        key.labelSecondary?.let {
            // Display secondary label if available
            Text(text = it,
                color = textColor,
                fontSize = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.key_textHintSize).value.sp,
                modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(createRef()) {
                    top.linkTo(parent.top, margin = 2.dp)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end, margin = 2.dp)
                })
        }

        if (key.shouldShowPopUp) {
            // Display a pop-up screen if Clicked
            PopupScreen(
                label = popUpLabel,
                isVisible = isPopupVisible.value
            )
        }

    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun CustomKeyPreview() {
    // Preview for CustomKey composable
    CustomKey(
        key = Key("f", 1F, labelSecondary = "@"),
        onKeyPressed = {},
        onDragGesture = {},
        onLongKeyPressed = {},
        onLongKeyPressedEnd = {},
        modifier = Modifier,
        onLayoutSwitchClick = {},
        onExtendedSymbolsSwitchClick = {},
        onNumbersSwitchClick = {},
        onSymbolsLayoutSwitchClick = { },
        onCapsClick = {},
        onCapsClickToLock = {},
        context = null
    )
}

fun onClick(
    isPopupVisible: MutableState<Boolean>, context: Context?, vibrator: Vibrator?
) {
    // Handle the click event on the key
    showPopUp(isPopupVisible)
    if (context != null) {
        playSound(context = context)
    }
    vibrate(vibrator)
}
```

Here is Keyboard layout.

```
package com.soloftech.keyboard.presentation.layout


import android.content.Context
import android.os.Vibrator
import android.util.Log
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.key
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.colorResource
import androidx.compose.ui.res.dimensionResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.soloftech.keyboard.R
import com.soloftech.keyboard.data.layout.extendedSymbolsLayout
import com.soloftech.keyboard.data.layout.numbersLayout
import com.soloftech.keyboard.data.layout.qwertyLayout_small
import com.soloftech.keyboard.data.layout.symbolsLayout
import com.soloftech.keyboard.domain.KeyboardVisibilityProvider
import com.soloftech.keyboard.domain.keyboard.LayoutState
import com.soloftech.keyboard.presentation.MainActivity
import com.soloftech.keyboard.presentation.service.CustomImeService

@Composable
fun CustomKeyboard(
    imeService: CustomImeService? = null,
    vibrator: Vibrator? = null,
    context: Context?,
    showNumbersRow: Boolean = false,
    imeActionType: Int? = null
) {
    // Define the height of the keyboard based on whether the numbers row should be shown
    val keyboardHeight = if (showNumbersRow) 248.dp else 208.dp

    // Mutable state variables for Caps and Caps Lock
    var isCapsEnabled by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    var isCapsLockEnabled by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    // Mutable state variable to track the current layout
    var currentLayout by remember { mutableStateOf(LayoutState.Qwerty) }

    // Detect changes in keyboard visibility
    var isKeyboardVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    KeyboardVisibilityProvider { isVisible ->
        isKeyboardVisible = isVisible
        if (!isKeyboardVisible) {
            // Keyboard is hidden, switch back to qwerty layout and disable Caps Lock
            currentLayout = LayoutState.Qwerty
            isCapsLockEnabled = false
        }
    }

    // Determine which keys to display based on the current layout
    var keys = when (currentLayout) {
        LayoutState.Qwerty -> qwertyLayout_small
        LayoutState.Symbols -> symbolsLayout
        LayoutState.ExtendedSymbols -> extendedSymbolsLayout
        LayoutState.Numbers -> numbersLayout
    }

    // Click handlers for layout switches
    val onLayoutSwitchClick = {
        currentLayout = LayoutState.Qwerty
    }

    val onNumbersSwitchClick = {
        currentLayout = LayoutState.Numbers
    }

    val onSymbolsLayoutSwitchClick = {
        currentLayout = LayoutState.Symbols
    }

    val onExtendedSymbolsSwitchClick = {
        currentLayout = LayoutState.ExtendedSymbols
    }

    // Click handler for Caps
    val onCapsClick = {
        if (isCapsLockEnabled) {
            isCapsLockEnabled = false
        } else {
            isCapsEnabled = !isCapsEnabled
        }
    }

    // Click handler to toggle Caps Lock
    val onCapsClickToLock = {
        isCapsLockEnabled = !isCapsLockEnabled
        isCapsEnabled = false
    }

    // Composable layout for the keyboard
    key(keys) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(keyboardHeight)
                .background(colorResource(id = R.color.KeyboardBackground)),
        ) {
            // Adjust the keys based on whether the numbers row is shown
            keys = keys.drop(if (!showNumbersRow && currentLayout == LayoutState.Qwerty) 1 else 0)
                .toTypedArray()
            keys.forEachIndexed { rowIndex, row ->
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(
                            horizontal = if (showNumbersRow) {
                                if (rowIndex == 2 && currentLayout == LayoutState.Qwerty) 16.dp
                                else dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.key_marginH).value.dp
                            } else {
                                if (rowIndex == 1 && currentLayout == LayoutState.Qwerty) 16.dp
                                else dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.key_marginH).value.dp
                            },
                            vertical = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.key_marginV).value.dp

                        ),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                ) {
                    row.forEach { key ->
                        CustomKey(
                            key = key,
                            isCapsEnabled = isCapsEnabled,
                            isCapsLockEnabled = isCapsLockEnabled,
                            onKeyPressed = {
                                if (key.isCharacter) {
                                    imeService?.commitText(
                                        key = key,
                                        isCapsEnabled = isCapsEnabled,
                                        isCapsLockEnabled = isCapsLockEnabled
                                    )
                                    if (!isCapsLockEnabled && isCapsEnabled) {
                                        isCapsEnabled = false
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    imeService?.doSomethingWith(key, false)
                                }
                            },
                            onDragGesture = { dragAmount ->
                                if (key.labelMain == "Delete") {
                                    Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "CustomKey: ${dragAmount.toString()}")
                                }
                            },
                            onLongKeyPressed = {
                                imeService?.doSomethingWith(key, true)
                                if (!isCapsLockEnabled && isCapsEnabled) {
                                    isCapsEnabled = false
                                }
                            },
                            onLongKeyPressedEnd = {
                                imeService?.longPressedStops()
                            },
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(horizontal = 2.dp)
                                .weight(key.weight),
                            onLayoutSwitchClick = {
                                onLayoutSwitchClick()
                            },
                            onExtendedSymbolsSwitchClick = {
                                onExtendedSymbolsSwitchClick()
                            },
                            onNumbersSwitchClick = {
                                onNumbersSwitchClick()
                            },
                            onSymbolsLayoutSwitchClick = {
                                onSymbolsLayoutSwitchClick()
                            },
                            onCapsClick = {
                                onCapsClick()
                            },
                            onCapsClickToLock = {
                                onCapsClickToLock()
                            },
                            context = context,
                            vibrator = vibrator,
                            imeAction = imeActionType
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun CustomKeyboardPreview() {
    CustomKeyboard(
        vibrator = null,
        context = null,
    )
}
```

I'm looking for suggestions or guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this delay issue with the popup. Has anyone encountered a similar problem, and what steps can I take to optimize the app and popup's performance?

Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: It would be great if you could truncate your code more to only show the most important parts (Popup, code that shows Popup, code that hides Popup). Also please show where you are modifying the `key.shouldShowPopUp` value and where your delay handler is.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

It appears that there is a bug with the Popup Composable causing a memory leak. Several people [reported it on the Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=Popup%20Memory%20Leak) in the last weeks. This might be related to the problem you are experiencing. 
For now, you can try to downgrade your Compose dependencies to an older version and see if the issue also is present there.

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.3.0" // use Compose Version 1.3.0
```

You might need to downgrade your other dependencies to match the same Compose version.

---

I am not sure how `Hander.postDelayed()` behaves in the context of Jetpack Compose. You might want to try using a `CoroutineScope` or a `LaunchedEffect` instead, for example like this:

```
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()  // in top of Composable
// ...
onTap = {
    // Handle tap gesture on the key
    isPopupVisible.value = true
    coroutineScope.launch{
        delay(250)
        isPopupVisible.value = false
    }
    // ...
}
```

Or you could also move the reponsability for handling the delay to the PopupScreen similar to this:

```
Composable
fun PopupScreen(
    label: String,
    isVisible: Boolean,
    onHide: () -> Unit
) {
    val popupWidth = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.key_width)
    val popupHeight = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.key_height)
    val cornerSize = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.key_borderRadius)

    LaunchedEffect(Unit){
        delay(250)
        onHide()
    }

    // ...
}
```

In the calling Composable, react to the `onHide` callback accordingly:

```
if (key.shouldShowPopUp) {
    // Display a pop-up screen if Clicked
    PopupScreen(
        label = popUpLabel,
        isVisible = isPopupVisible.value,
        onHide = { isPopupVisible.value = false }
    )
}
```

Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects) about `LaunchedEffect` and `rememberCoroutineScope`.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, It improves speed a little bit, but still not acceptable, I think it is popup issue.

Comment: If you could suggest something better that will be great. I had implemented custom popup layout. But that makes the layout bounds above it's boundaries that changes each row size for 250ms and then back to default.

Comment: So is there any way, I make a custom layout and that doesn't effect other layout. Like popup shows above others

Comment: @ShahZamanRai Try to further track down the issue. Is the delay also there if you show some other composable, for example replace your `PopupScreen()` Composable call with `if(isPopupVisible.value) {Text(text="Hello) }` and see if there is also a delay with the Text Composable being shown.

Comment: That doesn't have any delay, only pop-up causes delay.

Comment: @ShahZamanRai See my edited answer. I searched the Issue Tracker and found some recent problems related to the Popup Composable.

Comment: That doesn't made much improvement, a little yeah but not much. Do you have any idea i have some layout that serve as popup, how can I make that to not effect layout. It is a box with with a text inside it?

Comment: BTW, Thanks for answer.

Comment: I have no alternatives to suggest to use instead of the `Popup` Composable. My last idea is that you shoud try to build a release variant of your app with `minifyEnabled = true` in the `build.gradle` file. This usually increases performance of a Compose application drastically. See also this post: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/why-should-you-always-test-compose-performance-in-release-4168dd0f2c71